# Select first image from different feed rss items

Tags: php, rss

i have a problem: i have to get the first image that is on the items of different feed rss, i've tried the way found online but all of them won't work.
I think there is a logical error that i can't see..

Actually this is my code:

```
          while($dati = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  //get all the urls of some feed rss from db
          {
              $rss = simplexml_load_file($dati['url']); //load current feeds

              $items = $rss->channel->item;
              $cnt = count($rss->channel->item); //number of item in current feed
              for($y=0;$y<=$cnt;$y++) //check if there is an image on this item, if not, go to the next one
              {
                  $img = (string)$rss->channel->item[0]->description;
                  preg_match( '@src="([^"]+)"@' , $img, $match );
                  $src = array_pop($match);
                  if($src)
                  break; //if an img is found exit the cicle
  }
```

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return?

Comment: nothing appear..

Comment: What's the value of `$cnt` ?

Comment: Depends on the number of items in the rss feed currently being analyzed

Comment: You aren't printing anything, what's exactly the problem you're facing ?

Comment: is that when i try to display the img with the $src variable, only the image of one or two feed appear, the other src are empty, but other feed in at least one item have an img

Comment: someone can help?